# Resque.. how can I get a list of the queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, scheduled-tasks, resque

Ok.. On heroku I have up 24 workers (as I understand it)
I have say 1000 clients. Each with their own "schema" in a postgresql database.

each client has tasks that can be done "later".. sending orders to my companies back end, is a great example.

I was thinking that I could create a new queue for each client, and each queue would have it's own worker(process). That it seems isn't in the cards.

So ok.. my thinking now is to have a queue field in client record.. 
so client 1 through 15 are in queue_a
and client 16 through 106 are in queue_b.. ect  If one client is using heaps, we could move them to a new queue, or move others out of the slow Queue. clients with low volumns could be collected.. It would be a balancing act, but it wouldn't be all that hard to manage, if we kept track of metrics (which we will anyway)

**(any counter ideas would be awesome to hear, I'm really in spit ball phase)**

Right now, though. I'd like to figure out how to create a worker for each queue. 
https://gist.github.com/486161 tells me how to create X workers, but doesn't really let me set a worker to a Queue. If I knew that, and how to get a list of queues, I think I'd be on my way to a viable solution to the limits.

---

Reading on
http://blog.winfieldpeterson.com/2012/02/17/resque-queue-priority/
I realize that my plan is fraught with hardship.. The first client/queue to get added to the worker, would get priority.. I don't want that, I'd want them to all have the same.  As long as they are part of the same queue..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i just stick to the topic :)

getting all queues in resque is pretty easy

```
Resque.queues
```

is a list of all queue names, it does not include the 'failed' queue, i did something like this

```
(['failed'] + Resque.queues).each do |queue|
  queue_size = queue=='failed' ? Resque::Failure.count : Resque.size(queue)
end
```

Comment: Thanks heaps man.. I'm not sure it's the best approach, but it will let me have a worker for each que.. I might expand my thinking to have more than one queue per worker, but that would only be for priority.

Comment: do you know if the queues are alpha sorted?

Comment: [The call to `Redis.queues`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/8a8fd83f1f32755734f0068d9f211aeb2fda1f9e/lib/resque.rb#L253) uses the [SMEMBERS](http://redis.io/commands/SMEMBERS) operation on Redis. Because Redis is a key-value cache/store designed for speed, SMEMBERS does not try to sort the set members. So the answer to @baash05 's question is - no.